# Undo the last neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, undo

Neo4j community 2.0.

How can I undo the last successfully executed neo4j cypher query (made big changes by error).

And generally is there a chance to rollback to a particular state (at least what shown on the interface)?

Though, seems basic action, cannot find it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your cypher statements in a transaction then you can always rollback instead of committing.

- in the Neo4j-Shell or old Web-UI with `BEGIN .... COMMIT` around your queries use `ROLLBACK`
- with the new [transactional http endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html)
- with programmatic use, e.g. via the JAVA API and transactional boundaries
- with any of the drivers that support transactions with Neo4j: http://neo4j.org/drivers

Comment: Thanks @Michael-hunger for your reply. 

I am afraid I am clueless about what to do from the new browser: I executed:

START n=node(*) SET n.nomo = "*thorsten*" 

instead of 

START n=node(*) WHERE n.nomo = "*thorsten*" 

so I accidently changed the property "nomo" of all nodes to the single value "*thorsten*". 

Can I rollback that action?

Comment: If the transaction has been committed, the only chance is to restore from backup (if you have one).

Answer (score 0):

Well,
when a transaction is committed, there is really no clean way of rolling it back, except to write a new transaction that negates the older one. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, i wasn't using transactions and i rewritten the property of all nodes. So i guess, for my case, i have to go back to a prior backed up version of the db.                                        It is tedious to work without an integrated "backup" or "undo" function or "save" like in Neoclipse, which is unfortunately not enough mature : (